# Puppetter times out when opening a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

**Background**

I am running Puppeteer in an application locally that works fine. When I move it to a production debian server, it times out at the

`page.goto(url)` function.

**Example**

I have tried a bunch of different suggestions online. In the example below you will see a few options I have tried that were suggested on line. I have tried these all alone and in different combinations with each other. Yes I am that desperate at this point.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
        '--user-data-dir']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(
      `https://example.com/${template}?data=${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}
    );
```

page.goto(url) works locally, but fails when running on server.

**Question**

Why is `page.goto()` failing on the server and is there any work around?

Comment: Instead of `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'`, have you tried `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'`? How about `waitUntil: 'load'`?

Comment: If the website your going to returns a consistent view, a better option than `waitUntil`, would be `page.waitForSelector`.  Also are you running in headless mode, if so, try headless false so you can see what's happening..

Comment: `but fails when running on server` Could be just that your server IP is banned from accessing the target site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout` is your option

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
    '--user-data-dir']});

const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(3600); // 1 hour
await page.goto(
  `https://example.com/${template}?data=${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}
);
```

reference https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout